# convert string into format of table

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I have a string with JSON notation in VF page and I want to iterate over it and create a table.
I am trying to display in table but has not got anywhere. I am looking for some suggestion to achieve this.

This is the  String:

`{"label":[{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NpQAJ","Name":"Edge Communications,{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NqQAJ","Name":"Burlington Textiles Corp of
America"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NrQAJ","Name":"Pyramid Construction Inc."},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NwQAJ","Name":"University of
Arizona"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NxQAJ","Name":"United Oil & Gas, UK"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NsQAJ","Name":"Dickenson
plc"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NtQAJ","Name":"Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NyQAJ","Name":"United Oil & Gas,
Singapore"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NzQAJ","Name":"GenePoint"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3O0QAJ","Name":"sForce"},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NuQAJ","Name":"United
Oil & Gas Corp."},{"Id":"0017F00000Pf3NvQAJ","Name":"Express Logistics and Transport"}]}`

Comment: Create an apex class using json2apex (http://json2apex.herokuapp.com) and then store values to json to that object's attribute and finally display those in VFP

Comment: I have tried this but I am receiving this error: `sorry, unable to parse your json: Unexpected character ('I' (code 73)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [Source: java.io.StringReader@43d33e1b; line: 1, column: 68]`

Answer (score 0):

Create an apex class as follows using [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com)

```
public class JSON2Apex {

    public List<Label> label;

    public class Label {
        public String id;
        public String Name;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

Then, create a visualforce page and controller class to display those values in VFP.